# How to get HttpServletRequest object in Spring Schedular (@Schedule)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to send a mail using spring scheduler. In that I need HttpServletRequest object to create webContext, so that I can send mail using thyme leaf.
Anyone know the answer of this. Thanks in advance. Code is as follows,

```
    @Async
    private void sendNotification(String toField, Users user, int currentMonth)
            throws Exception {

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

               **//here i need request object**
        final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, request.getSession()
                .getServletContext(), request.getLocale());

        ctx.setVariable("eagletId", user.getEagletId());
        ctx.setVariable("name", user.getFirstName());
        ctx.setVariable("setSentDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("department", user.getDepartment());
        ctx.setVariable("batch", user.getBatch());

        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
        helper.setTo(user.getEmail());


        // create html body using thymeleaf
        final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("email.html",
                ctx);
        helper.setText(htmlContent, true);
        mailSender.send(message);

    }
```

Comment: A servlet request only lives from a request is initiated until the response is written back to the client. After that, you can't safely reference it, since it will be re-used for other requests. Therefore, you can't reference it in an asynchronous operation like that. You have to pass your information by other means.

Comment: Hi NilsH, Thanks for your reply. But how can I achieve this.

Comment: Create a non-WebContext instead. Read here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/springmail.html. And then store the values in a database so you can retrieve them in your task.